# How do the Doctor Who audio dramas of past doctors fit in with tv continuity?

Tags: doctor-who

I've just been wondering where the audios of, say the Sixth Doctor in Jubilee would fit in with his tv timeline. **I'm not asking if they are canonical**, just whether there are mentions of the audio dramas fitting between episodes of the show or if it is just hand waved as an unspecified time (which I am kinda hoping it is).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Little effort is made to coordinate the timelines of different Dr. Who series written by different authors. Since there is no official canon, the creations made at whatever times are able to be used in whatever fashion authors see fit.

I suspect that is the primary reason there is no canon because the Doctor can be anywhere at any time except when he is in a particular adventure. (And to be honest, we have even seen multiple Doctors appear at a single moment in time if the writer is adventurous or crazed enough. **See: [The Time of the Doctor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Time_of_the_Doctor))** This means if you want the Doctor to know or remember something you simply have to have a story appear soon after a particular televised or written event.

This lack of canon is both liberating and annoying from a fan perspective, since it becomes almost impossible to have a complete reference of all the divergent canon in a single place at one time. The **[Tardis Data Core](http://tardis.wikia.com/)** is a fine example of an attempt to list all the episodes of a particular phenomenon or character in a single cohesive attempt.

Dating those events is only done in relationship to the events if a date was specified. Otherwise, writers mix and match as they see fit, utilizing previous events as they need for background.

Comment: RTD and Moffat have both said that time travel makes canon impossible, but Old Who just didn't seem to care; the show started up in an era where syndication and re-runs weren't really a thing so continuity was less important.

Comment: I am of the opinion there should be a very loose canon/continuity so a writer can feel free to just write their story without having to add in extraneous elements. I thought of this question because I would like to see new Ninth Doctor novels at some point, without them having to feel burdened by the continuity of the single season he appeared in. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: The thing is that the Doctor CAN be in anywhere at any time but usually tends not to cross his own timestream... The only moments that he does there are usually reasons as to why he is able to do so, and also reasons as to why it was allowed to happen and how it resolves itself as well.